# R: f(x) != sapply(x,f) -- bug or feature?

Tags: r, apply

```
> f =  function(x) as.Date(as.character(x), format='%Y%m%d')
> f(20110606)
[1] "2011-06-06"
> sapply(20110606, f)
[1] 15131
```

Why 2 returned values are not the same. I need to apply this function to a long vector of dates, but I'm not getting dates with sapply()!

Comment: Documented in `?sapply`: "Value: ... an atomic vector or matrix or list of the same length as 'X'".  The Date class is not atomic (the atomic types are listed later in the paragraph I quote). This is the same reason you can't use a Date vector as the iterator in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
> lapply(20110606, f)
[[1]]
[1] "2011-06-06"

> unlist(lapply(20110606, f))
[1] 15131
```

`sapply` unlists lapply and in doing so unclasses the date

```
> unclass(lapply(20110606, f)[[1]])
[1] 15131
> class(lapply(20110606, f)[[1]])
[1] "Date"
```

as @Joshua Ulrich noted there is no need to use apply type functions however for interest

```
 d <- 20110606 + 0:10
 do.call("c",lapply(d, f))
```

would be one possible way to "unlist" the dates

Comment: I need to get a vector to attach it to a dataframe. What do I do?

Comment: That `do.call` with `c` is a handy tip. Still, it's a pity there isn't an `unlist` or `sapply` which doesn't unclass.

Answer (score 8):

The functions you use to create `f` are already vectorized. There's no need to use `sapply`, unless you work for the Department of Redundancy Department.

```
> f <- function(x) as.Date(as.character(x), format='%Y%m%d')
> d <- 20110606 + 0:10
> f(d)
 [1] "2011-06-06" "2011-06-07" "2011-06-08" "2011-06-09"
 [5] "2011-06-10" "2011-06-11" "2011-06-12" "2011-06-13"
 [9] "2011-06-14" "2011-06-15" "2011-06-16"
```